# Calculating Weighted Quantiles causing NA error by coercion in R

Tags: r, weighted-data

I'm new to R and I'm trying through two different packages and formulas to calculate quantiles from a weighted dataset, as you can see below:

```
library(MetricsWeighted)
library(stats)
library(reldist)

data <- read.csv("paradeciles.csv",encoding = "UTF-8")

x<- data$Gasto_mensual

w<- data$factor

x2 <- data$Ingreso_mensual

weighted_quantile(x,w,
  probs = seq(0.1,.9,.1),
  na.rm = T,
  names = T)


wtd.quantile(x2,na.rm=T,weight = w,q = .5)
```

In both formulas, a value is calculated (with a clearly wrong result) and I get the following warning message:

Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, setLab = FALSE) : NAs introducidos por coerción

As you can see I'm having the same issue with both x and x2. A few rows of x are blank, but none in x2... so I'm guessing that can't be the issue.

The data frame I'm using looks like this:

[image]

Any advice as to how I may get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and was able to solve the problem with the following declarations:

```
x<- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data$Gasto_mensual))
x2 <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data$Ingreso_mensual))
```

With gsub I get rid of commas, and with as.numeric I make sure R is treating the vectors as numbers (or so I think!).

Cheers and all the best,

Comment: Hint: It is usually much more elegant to read the data in the correct format (numbers as numbers etc.) instead of coercing afterward.